# How to define the size of a tuple or a list in the type hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, parameter-passing, type-hinting

Is there a way to define the size of a tuple or list in the type hints of arguments?

At the moment I am using something like this:

```py
    from typing import List, Optional, Tuple

    def function_name(self, list1: List[Class1]):
        if len(list1) != 4:
            raise SomeError()
        pass
        # some code here
```

I am searching for a leaner way to do this.

Comment: See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7626

Comment: Look into using `collections.deque`. You can set a maxLen on it. You could also create your own List class that inherits from `collections.UserList` that enforces size limitations.

Comment: The docs for Tuple and List clearly state if/how this is possible. What part do you need clarification on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify length of Sequence or List with Python typing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833822/specify-length-of-sequence-or-list-with-python-typing-module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For lists it make no sense because they are dynamic, for tuples on the other hand the number of types inside the definition is the number of elements it holds:

```
from typing import Tuple

example_1: Tuple[int, int] = (1, 2)  # This is valid
example_2: Tuple[int, int] = (1, 2, 3)  # This is invalid
example_3: Tuple[int, ...] = (1, 2, 3, 4)  # This is valid, the ellipses means any number if ints
example_4: Tuple[int, ...] = (1, 'string')  # This is invalid

# So in your case if you need 4 you can do something like this
My4Tuple = Tuple[Class1, Class1, Class1, Class1]
def my_function(self, arg1: My4Tuple):
    pass
```

Always remember that this is not enforced at runtime

Comment: If `x: Tuple[int, float] = [1, 2.0]` is invalid, is there any built-in type instead of Tuple that would work with assigning a list of mixed types?

Comment: @Vic your annotation is valid, there can be mixed types, in my example I'm not mixing types in the annotation thus I said invalid for mixed values, but you annotated correctly and as long as the tuple holds the annotated values it will be fine

Comment: `mypy` complains about my annotation example: `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[float]", variable has type "Tuple[int, float]")`

Comment: Old question I know but stumbling on it and thought I'd answer. The issue isn't your annotation, it's that `[1.0, 2]` is a `List` (the brackets!). Change it to `(1, 2.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change the signature to accept 4 parameters:

```
def function_name(self, c1, c2, c3, c4): # Use better parameter names
    pass
```

Then you can call this with a list by using the splat operator:

```
l = [...]
x.function_name(*l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have it take in 4 arguments? Then, you can do something like this:

```
def function_name(self, a: Class1, b: Class1, c:Class1, d:Class1):
    ...

data = (Class1(...), Class1(...), Class1(...), Class1(...))
obj.function_name(*data)
```

Comment: It would work for the specific question not so much for a huge list/tuple.