# type hinting tuples of fixed but rather large fixed length

Tags: python, type-hinting

I currently type hint a function returning tuple as follows:

```
FuncOutput = Tuple[nib.Nifti1Image,
                   nib.Nifti1Image,
                   nib.Nifti1Image,
                   nib.Nifti1Image,
                   nib.Nifti1Image,
                   nib.Nifti1Image,
                   nib.Nifti1Image]
```

Is there a way to do this in a concise manner where I can specify the length without typing it so many times?

Comment: I only know the `Tuple[nib.Nifti1Image, ...]` syntax that doesn't specify the length, but have you tried something like `Tuple[*[nib.Nifti1Image]*7]`. I have low expectations though.

Comment: @Adirio, you don't need to unpack list, use tuple instead `Tuple[(nib.Nifti1Image,) * 7]`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght would any of these two solutions (list unpacking or tuple) work in type hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify length of Sequence or List with Python typing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833822/specify-length-of-sequence-or-list-with-python-typing-module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. [`typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) only supports typing each element or a variable number of elements.

Comment: No, you're not right. `Tuple[(nib.Nifti1Image,) * 7]` will work.

Comment: @OlvinRoght are you sure that gets translated to `Tuple[nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image]` and not to `Tuple[(nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image, nib.Nifti1Image)]`? Notice the brackets in the second one.

Comment: @Adirio, yes, I am sure.

Comment: @OlvinRoght ``mypy`` rejects that as ``error: Invalid type comment or annotation``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, [check](https://repl.it/repls/PhonyDarkmagentaCygwin)

Comment: @OlvinRoght That is not a static type annotation/hint. It is a runtime representation, which can of course be constructed in arbitrary ways. One could in principle use ``exec`` to construct such a runtime type – that does not make it a valid static type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type variable.

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
tuple7 = tuple[T, T, T, T, T, T, T]
# then you can write
FuncOutput = tuple7[nib.Nifti1Image]
```