# Individually specifying all the variables in a type hint

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Consider this example dataclass which contains a variable `x` which is a list of 5 integers. What is the correct way to write the type hint? Individually specifying all 5 `int` values in the `list` seems cumbersome? What if my list was `N` elements long and `N` was very big?

```py
@dataclass
class Example:
    x: list[int, int, int, int, int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Can I just write:

```py
@dataclass
class Example:
    x: list[int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Or is there another way I can write the type hint to indicate to the user that this list is always 5 elements long?

Comment: Have a look at [Specify length of Sequence or List with Python typing module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44833822/5168011)

Comment: Thanks - that has answered my question