# Pydantic issue for tuple length

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following model in pydantic (Version 2.0.3)

```
from typing import Tuple
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    test_field: Tuple[int]
```

But when I enter

```
model = Model(test_field=(1,2))
```

I get as error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/tobi/Documents/scraiber/z_legacy/fastapi_test_app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 150, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Model
test_field
  Tuple should have at most 1 item after validation, not 2 [type=too_long, input_value=(1, 2), input_type=tuple]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.3/v/too_long
```

Do you know how I can fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following **@Tim Robert**'s Answer, the linked PR suggests using the [Ellipsis `...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-ellipsis-object) is the syntax you're after!

https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/pull/512/files

```py
class Model(BaseModel):
    test_field: Tuple[int, ...]
```

```py
>>> Model(test_field=(1,2))
Model(test_field=(1, 2))
```

Comment: Many thanks for it. 

Assume, for instance, I have 100 `int` in a tuple. Is there a more elegant way to do instead of the two you mentioned?

Comment: I think the general advice is "don't do that" and a lot of fields is probably a bad design .. but if you do have a lot of fields, consider a NamedTuple https://stackoverflow.com/a/44833864/4541045 (which at least annotates the values).. you'll have to either provide every field (`[int, int, int, int, int]`), create a custom Type with that many fields, or use `...` and an `@field_validator` to assert the length https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/

Answer (score 0):

Variable-length tuples are not supported.  There's a bug report about it.  `Sequence` can be used as a workaround.

https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/495

Comment: You missed the fact that this issue has been closed as fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/commit/fe72ba13f469377057112d2f301f52cd3b206467) a few years ago. Variable length tuples **are** supported.